Movie about a school massacre and hostage situation
First: This is not Michael Moore's "Bowling for Columbine". The movie starts with a blond boy who wrote a letter to his mother that explains his insane thing and asks her to forgive him. He exits the house and goes to a school (probably his former school) and he kills with a gun a black student, then takes other students as hostages and becomes friendly(!) with them. He also asks if they (the students) want something to eat and orders a pizza  (sic!)
A policeman, of course good and quiet, tries to convince him to release students and after some times he releases students and gets caught. Someone knows the title?

Years: about 1993-96
Country: USA
Other info: probably a TV-movie,it was released in Italy


Sounds like Detention: The Siege at Johnson High (1997) with Ricky Schroder and    Freddie Prinze Jr.

A former high school student, Jason Copeland, returns to his school to take his revenge on the teachers for failing him out of school.

Pretty much everything you described is there. He's blonde, he takes hostages and eventually becomes more friendly and orders food. A hostage negotiator convinces him to release the hostages and give up in the end. This TV movie was based on a real event. Here's the trailer:



